# Two column in mobile landscape view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to show one column in mobile portrait view and two column for mobile landscape view using getbootstrap 3. In the desktop version, there should be three column instead.

I used this code

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
```

But couldn't get single column on portrait view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/jdanyow/EVTsX/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row col-md-8">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col1">col 1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col2">col 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col3">col 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```